# CMS для сайта-визитки

Tags: framework, php, cms, html, движок

Необходима CMS для сайта-визитки, с возможностью добавлять небольшие новости.
Самая важная и ключевая особенность, это несложное "натягивание" шаблонов (html+css). Для этих целей подходит DLE, но в ней много лишнего. Так же, было бы отличным плюсом присутствие базы данных на файлах. Что можете подсказать?

Comment: Чем вас пугает лишний функционал?

Comment: @Etki, ненадобностью.

Comment: @XenK ну так не пользуйтесь им.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте взглянуть на [GetSimple CMS](http://get-simple.info/). Довольно проста в установке и настройке. Натягивание шаблонов проходит быстро и есть пошаговая инструкция. Данные хранятся в XML.

Answer (score 1):

CMS с файловой БД:

- [monstra](http://monstra.org/)
- [picocms](http://picocms.org/) ([twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)) и ее форк [philecms](http://philecms.com/)

MySQL:

- [anchorcms](http://anchorcms.com/)

Пользовался picocms. Для нее есть готовые плагины rss, sitemap, теги и прочее.
Думаю следующую буду использовать monstra.

Также был сайтик на anchorcms. Очень быстрая и легкая. Слабом хостинге (бесплатно) висела и особо проблем с ресурсами не испытывала. Выдерживала до 2к посещений в день.

Answer (score 0):

Добрый вечер! Судя по Вашему посту, могу сказать, что все движки каким-то образом содержат "лишние функции". Никто не знает, кому что пригодится. ;-) Хотя я работал далеко не со всеми движками, а только топовая его часть (Wordpress, Joomla, DLE...). Правильный ответ - это написать движок самому. Или урезать (подделать под себя вышеуказанные движки). Это чисто мое мнение.

Comment: Свой движок для сайта визитки - это явно утопия.

Comment: А если назвать его не движок, а набор готовых функций/скриптов.

Comment: > Правильный ответ - это написать движок самому. 

NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO

Comment: Etki, я понимаю, что зачем создавать велосипед, но мне лично проще что-то мелкое самому написать, чем использовать готовое. Но это мое ИМХО

Comment: @Node_pro, никто не спорит, что лучше всё самому и для себя делать. Но тратить время на то что уже создано, я не вижу смысла. В крайнем случае можно переделать что-то готовое.

Comment: > Правильный ответ - это написать движок самому.

Правильный ответ - это написать операционную систему самому! Ведь Windows, Linux, MacOS - это набор лишнего функционала, и вполне вероятно, что Вы не будете использовать и половины!

Если у автора хватит знаний писать что-то своё - то лучше использовать легковесный фреймворк. Иначе CMS с большим комьюнити.

Answer (score 0):

Года 3 назад использовал для нескольких проектов [CMF MODx Revo](http://modx.com/). Выделяется на фоне остальных интересным [шаблонизатором](http://docs.modx.pro/system/basics/syntax-tags). Из коробки не перегружен. Необходимые пакеты (плагины) можно скачать [здесь](http://modx.com/extras/category/site-packages), либо удалённо через админку. Достаточно неплохая поддержка со стороны русскоязычного комьюнити: [modxclub.ru](http://modxclub.ru/), [community.modx-cms.ru](http://community.modx-cms.ru/), [modx.ru](http://modx.ru/). Можете почитать посты на хабре двух людей, которые внесли заметный вклад в данный проект с точки зрения популяризации: [Николай "fi1osof" Ланец](http://habrahabr.ru/users/Fi1osof/) ([github](https://github.com/Fi1osof/), [youtube канал](http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUHOfQLhr4V85-UnBHSyr9g)) и [Василий "bezumkin" Наумкин](http://habrahabr.ru/users/bezumkin/) ([github](https://github.com/bezumkin/), [youtube канал](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-3gFM3Vwx17P4pTZ3lf2RA)). Последний занимается переводом [оф. документации](http://docs.modx.pro).

Из недостатков: достаточно медленное поведение адимнки на shared-хостинге. Привет [ExtJS(Sencha)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_JS)! В [облаке](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V5Shvd4dGNM) таких проблем не наблюдается.

Answer (score 0):

Пишите сами, будет и надёжнее (если нормально напишете) и не будет лишнего функционала, который не нужен. Именно вашем случае, как вы хотите БД на файлах, это пишется минут за 40 максимум. А так советую в сторону mysql и PDO смотреть, один раз понять, зато потом всегда грамотно писать будете.

Comment: @pingvi, написать можно всегда. Нужна CMS.

Comment: @pingvi

> Именно вашем случае, как вы хотите БД на файлах, это пишется минут за 40 максимум.

ооой

Comment: 40 минут это заварить чай и включить компьютер.

Answer (score 0):

Да что за бред написать движок для сайта визитки. По-моему, можно взять абсолютно любой бесплатный движок и сделать сайт визитку. Все там уже есть, лишнее можно не использовать. Просто похоже, что человек не совсем сам понимает, что ему вообще нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Просто устанавливаете wordpress, перезаписиваете шаблон, и все.

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем случае я бы использовал генератор статических сайтов, выбрав подходящий на сайте http://www.staticgen.com/

Answer (score 0):

Используйте Битрикс. Там как раз есть решение "Сайт-визитка". Правда за его приобретение платить надо.

Comment: @TCHProgrammer, это явно не то, что мне нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать и не CMS, сейчас PHP framework, установленный из коробки, это уже готовый сайт-визитка. Не знаю про Lavarel, но Symfony2 и Yii2 подразумевают, что после установки у вас уже будет готовый сайт с минимальным функционалом (например, новости и обратная связь), на который остаётся только натянуть дизайн. Да и различные модули для framework'ов уже зачастую написаны, если не хотите писать свои с нуля.

Очевидные плюсы такого подхода, если вам нужно немного изменить фукнционал чего-либо, вам не нужно перебирать тонны гавнокода, которые обычно обитают в CMS. Ну и очевидно, что framework работает быстрее, чем любая из CMS. Натягивание CSS и JS тоже пройдёт без подводных камней в виде запрятанных где-то в  CMS шаблонов и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

CMS LinX неплохой вариант [CMS LinX](http://linxcms.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте ModX. Шаблоны более менее прозрачные.

Answer (score -1):

Сайт визитку можно сделать на системе Wordpress. Бесплатный движок, не прихотлив к хостингу. Легко найдете людей, которые смогут вам его доделать в случае необходимости.